# How to count all classes with the @Controllers attribute in your spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Once a interviewer asked me this question and I could not answer it. I also searched on Google but I am not getting any proper answer.

Comment: I think probably from the application classpath, you can, using reflection

Comment: at runtime? or what?

Comment: Probably using `Map<String,Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);`

Comment: Why are we using Foo.class here? i am not getting it ? and what if i want to know the count of controllers  from whole project ?

Comment: Ops... sorry, It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This may helpful...

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext =SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        Map<String,Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);
        System.out.println(beans.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use "RestController" in place of "Controller" as well.

Answer (score 4):

Please try below given code.

```
Map<String,Object> beans = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);
System.out.println(beans.size());
```

or you can try this with reflection library. Below given snippet can search in whole project.

maven dependency:

> org.reflections
>       reflections
>       0.9.10

```
import org.reflections.Reflections;

public class FindAnnotation {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Scanning using Reflections:");

    Reflections ref = new Reflections("com.some.package");
    for (Class<?> cl : ref.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)) {
        //count
    }
}}
```

Comment: Okay Thanx I will Try

Answer (score 1):

This would certainly depend on the way you will be trying to count your `Controller` beans.

### Programming way

The previously suggested solution would be a good fit if you will counting your beans through a custom deployed utility (i.e. the implemented method should be in class able to access the `ApplicationContext` at runtime).

Meanwhile you should pay attention to `Controller` beans that are deployed conditionally.

### Spring Actuator

If you have the *Spring Actuator* activated and beans inspection enabled, you can simply hit the deployed endpoint to get the available beans and filter the *JSON* output to get your `*Controller` beans.